# Jekyill - Pass variable as parameter

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

It's been all the morning having this situation and I'm going crazy with it.

I have 2 files, a.html and b.html, I created a Jekyll tag with the name `render_menu_options`, the `parent_name` parameter returns name of a subdirectory of the actual menu, the `parent_name` value is passed in the `route_filter` parameter of the include function, but in the `render_menu_options` the actual value is always the name of the parameter, in this case `include.route_filter`

a.html

```
{% render_menu_options level:2 iterator:item sort:menu_order level_name:parent_name %}
<div class="menu-header">
  {{ item.text }}
</div>

<ul class="menu-container">
  <li>
    {% assign abc = parent_name %}
    parent_name: {{ abc }}
  </li>
  {% include s.html route_filter=parent_name %}
</ul>

{% endrender_menu_options %}
```

b.html

```
<ul class="menu-container">
{% render_menu_options level:3 iterator:subitem part_name:include.route_filter part_number:1 sort:menu_order %}
  <li>
      <a href="{{ subitem.url }}">
          {{ subitem.text }}
      </a>
  </li>
{% endrender_menu_options %}
</ul>
```

It is possible to pass the value of the parameter to the tag?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to spot where is the real problem without your plugin's code.

You can always try to put curly braces around your variable name.

```
{% render_menu_options level:3 iterator:subitem 
part_name:{{ include.route_filter }} part_number:1 sort:menu_order %}
```

Comment: remove the spaces:  `part_name:{{include.route_filter}}`